# Multiline content/html-ish content loadable through AJAX in Fancytree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-multiline.html

show nodes with (arbitrary) markup. Is this feature only available for trees generated from a existing DOM
or is it possible load to HTMLish nodes over AJAX? At least using

```
'title' : '<em>some text</em>'
```

inside the JSON does not work and lead to a parser issue on the client side.

Any way how to generate this properly on the JSON level?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? Can you make a working demo?

Comment: This is the typical Stackoverflow way to answer to clear questions? "What have you tried?"...clearly stated within the question that I tried myself and stated that it gives a parser error. So what?

Comment: Why are valid comments being censored?

Comment: I would guess that your previous comment was removed because it was inappropriate. Calling @alan0xd7 'stupid' for posting a valid comment, might be perceived as insulting - and obviously is no good strategy to get fast responses on SO

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If you get a parser error, you probably got your json wrong (for example the snippet you posted is invalid since it uses single quotes)
Otherwise please post the exact error or set up s.th. like a jsFiddle

Comment: How about posting a usable reply? I clearly stated that the issue is related to HTML tags...see the code snippet....and don't consider everyone as an idiot....the question is clear: how to use html tags properly here at all.